# So many retransmission over NSX enabled vDS of vSphere

Tags: vmware-esxi, tcpip, openvswitch

I'm currently on test of VMware NSX network environment and met some trouble.

My Environment is:

> - Management Cluster with 3 Hosts and NSX components on 2 dedicated Hosts
> - Compute Cluster with 2 Hosts
> - Single 1Gbps Switch
> - vSphere version 6.0 and NSX version 6.2
> - One dedicated UTP line per all Host for Management and iSCSI(VLAN tagged)
> - One dedicated UTP line per all Host for Transit Network(for VM traffic)
> - One dedicated UTP line per Management Host for External Network

When a `VM V` on `Host H` send data to `VM W` on `Host I` over NSX network, heavy restransmission is occurred. I tested many cases below:

Cases with Problem:

1. `V` send about 20MB to `W` in single session: retransmission at around 19MB
2. `V` send about 50MB to `W` in single session: retransmission at 19MB only
3. `V` send about 2MB to `W` in 30 concurrent sessions: retransmission at random position.

When this condition, I found some packet order mismatches (maybe cause of retransmission) on packet dump from `H`'s `vmnic`(uplink), and delayed packets are uniq(not occur previously on dump), but on dump from `vDS` downlink to VM `V` or `sfw` of `V`, they are occurred twice(original packets and retransmitted packets).
So I think, the problem is some lost packets on sender side stack especially between VM `V` and Host `H`'s Physical NIC.

To divide the data path/stack into two sectors and to check independantly, I tested same cases with another destination VM `X` on same Host `H`. then I got clean dump and I found there is no retransmissions problem between VMs on same Host. (so I think, there is no error point on vDS itself and above.)

Next, I tested cases below to check the problem is related on heavy data traffic or heavy filtering and/or encapsulation or not:

1. same test with `Network I/O Control` enabled: same problem
2. same test without `Network I/O Control`: same problem with some diffs.
3. same test but slowdown the throuput with `N I/O C Limit`: same problem
4. same test with `TSO` disabled `vnic` of `V`(e1000 driver): same problem
5. same test with `vDS` `MTU` 9000: same problem with more Question

Some different things are:

When `Network I/O Control` is enabled, At first, `RTT` is increased just before the restransmission and then after retransmission os completed, `RTT` values are in stable range.

But when `Network I/O Control` is disabled, `RTT` after restransmission also incleased again as same as start.

One ore strange thing is although I set `MTU` to 9000, the size of UTP packets which is embed VxLAN packets are under 1600. so effect of `MTU 9000` is not affected.

I'm on trouble. can I get some helps?
Thanks.

---

**EDIT ---**

If the VMs are on the normal, `NSX` disabled, `vDS`, all is fine.

---

**EDIT***
Is there any similar issues on OpenvSwitch?

Comment: Since this is a heavy set of features, have you checked with VMware support yet?

Comment: In fact, This test is PoC of the product and I am a customer (Engineer role).  I did with VMware's Pre-sales engineer and Partner engineers (both ESXi specialists and NSX specialists) but they cannot found the reason and problem point. :-(

Comment: Given 6.2 is very new you must inherently have a valid support contract with them, so they HAVE to formally investigate this for you - just log a case with them and they'll sort it - they'll want a million log files off you but that's the only way forward - NSX is VERY complex (for a start you've not even mentioned your VTAM setup here) and you've provided only part of the information needed to get to the bottom of this issue.